# ¿Como hago que pow me retorne el número ingresado por el usuario elevado al cuadrado?

Tags: c

1.este código es para calcular el valor al cuadrado del numero ingresado por el usuario,sin embargo cuando se trata de imprimir el valor calculado retorna 0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

/*Limpieza de pantalla*/
clrscr();

void main()
{

    ``/*Declaración de variables*/
    int i,a;double N[101],CD[101],E;
    E=2;
    /*datos usuario*/
  for(i=1;i<=100;i+=1){
    printf("Introduzca el %d numero:\n ",i);
    scanf("%f",&N[i]);
    CD[i]= pow(N[i], E);
  }
  /*Impresión de datos*/
  for(a=1;a<=100;a+=1){
    printf("\n %1f^2=%1f \n",N[a],CD[a]);
  }
  getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La cuestión es que las variables intentar leerlas como `float` mientras que tus arreglos son `doble`, para leer datos de tipo double debes utilizar `"%lf"`.

```
int main()
{

    int i;double N[100],CD[100],E;
    E=2;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        printf("Introduzca el %d numero:\n ",i+1);
        scanf("%lf",&N[i]);
        CD[i] = pow(N[i], E);
    }

    for(i = 0;i<100;i++){
        printf("\n %1lf^2=%1lf \n",N[i],CD[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```